# Extracting contents of compressed file without saving

Tags: c#, zip, compression, extract, c#-ziparchive

I have a compressed file (.osz) stored on an S3 Bucket which contains a .os file which I need to read the contents of.
I need to be able to extract/decompress and read the contents of the compressed file without downloading the file directly to the PC due to security reasons.

I am able to retrieve the compressed file (.osz) using the URL address of it's S3 Bucket path. Then using ZipArchive I am able to access the files contained within the compressed file. I am then able to extract the file I require by using the 'ExtractToFile' function as seen below. However, this function extracts the file (.os) and saves it locally in the path specified.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
                byte[] bytes = client.DownloadData(OSZFilepath); // Read the .osz file contents into a byte array

                using (MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    // Create the zip containing the file from the stream
                    ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream);
     
                    // extract the compressed file and download the .os file contained within
                    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".OS";
                    var baseDirectory = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataStorage"].ToString());
                    zip.Entries[0].ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "ProjectFiles", fileName));
```

Although this extracted file can be successfully read and imported by my program, I cannot use this method as I am not able to save the file onto the user's computer due to security restrictions and program requirements.

Therefore I need to programmatically extract/decompress the file I need in order to read the contents and programmatically import it into my program.

I have tried to use the following code to do this:

```
ZipArchiveEntry entry = zip.GetEntry(zip.Entries[0].Name);
                    Stream stream = entry.Open();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

However the resulting contents throws up an error when I try to import it, indicating that the contents is different to the contents of the file that gets saved using 'ExtractToFile'.

This is confirmed when I save this contents as a seperate file and compare it to the file saved using 'ExtractToFile'. The 'ExtractToFile' file is bigger than the latter.

So my question is: is there another way to successfully decompress/extract a compressed file and obtain the contents without using the 'ExtractToFile' method and having to save the extracted file somewhere?

Comment: 1) What kind of size differences? Is this a difference in counting characters (Length) vs file bytes (and in counted in KB or KiB)?; 2) Check out the source for ExtracToFile, to see how it works

Comment: I'm curious... where are you getting your reference to `ZipArchive`?  Is from the System.IO.Compression NuGet package by Microsoft?  If so, I don't see an `ExtractToFile()` method on the reference to `zip.Entries[0]`.  I do, however, see a `.Open()` method which returns a stream that contains the file data without having to persist it to disk.  Does that help at all?